# Snapshot testing ChartJS components with Jest

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, jestjs, react-chartjs

I am writing some jest snapshot tests for my react component that uses ChartJS v2. My test for a `Customer` component looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import CustomerComponent from '../src/components/customer/Customer';

describe('Customer', () => {
  it('renders customer', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Customer customerId={291}/>
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

When I run it with jest, I get this

```
 FAIL  tests/Customer.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: window is not defined

      at node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.helpers.js:672:10
      at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports (node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.helpers.js:680:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js:6:31)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-chartjs-2/lib/index.js:20:14)
```

It seems ChartJS expects a window object to be defined which is not available since this is not running in a browser. Is there a way to get snapshot tests to work with ChartJS?

Comment: I feel the title does not represent you question or objective. IMO, the title expresses, that you'd like to test the chart itself, rather than *a page which originally contained a chart and should now contain a mock*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just mock out the chart component from `react-chartjs-2`

```
jest.mock('react-chartjs-2', () => 'Chart')
```

This will replace the original component with a dump one that will just render as `<Chart prop="prop">` in your snapshot.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!